# Close modal after form success

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a modal and form inside, i want to close modal after form success.It's clean to give handleClose into ForgotPasswordFormComponent ? Or there is an another way ?

```
<StyledModal
open={openModal}
onClose={handleClose}
closeAfterTransition
slots={{ backdrop: StyledBackdrop }}
>
    <Box style={{
    width: 400,
    borderRadius: '12px',
    padding: '16px 32px 24px 32px',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    boxShadow: `0px 2px 24px #383838`,
    }}>
        <ForgotPasswordFormComponent  />
    </Box>
</StyledModal>
```

Comment: Yes, passing functions as props is common way to handle child-to-parent actions in React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option, as suggested in the comments (the most optimized, readable, and scalable one), is "Yes, passing functions as props is a common way to handle child-to-parent actions in React."

Another option (not recommended in this case, it's a questionable approach that can lead to unnecessary renders and dissatisfaction within the development team) is to use context.

If the question was about other possible options, I believe I've covered it. But essentially, you can write anything in any way in such cases.